# Creating a file using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to create files in plain JavaScript only?

Actually, I am using a static hosting provider (Neocities) and so I want a flat file system at least to store my records.

I can only work with plain JavaScript as Node JS in not supported.

I tried to use some functions from google searches but all of them were for client-side file generation.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. In particular it's not clear what you're asking here as you seem to be talking about using server-side Javascript but you also say your host provider does not support node.js.

Comment: you cannot create files one the file system using JS in browser

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

Learn what a client side and a server side application means really

While you can create file in client-side, there is **no way** you can save them